# Rotate a page 180 degrees in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How can I rotate a page 180 degrees in LaTeX?

Comment: what would be the point? 

if it's really needed, it might be easier to rotate the final ps/pdf

Comment: This question should be moved to http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15):

```
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{landscape}
Some text
\end{landscape}
```

Or for the whole document:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
```

Edit: This would of course only rotate the page by 90°... Sorry. ;)

Comment: That would be 90 degrees, wouldn't it?

Comment: Oh. Well... Yes. :) Shame on me. Sorry.

Comment: I fount this answer looking for a 90 degrees rotation, so it was still useful to me, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the *rotating* package?

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Rotating

This would rotate the content you put between *begin* and *end*. Do you need a designated page to be rotated you can achieve it using `\newpage` and `\clearpage.`:

To answer your question in the comments, I don't know how to achieve this within one single  environment if you are going to use different types of content (text, images...) within the `turn` environment. That depends a lot on what you exactly want to achieve.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\title{Test document}
\author{Wesho}
\date{18/06/2009}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newpage

\begin{rotate}{180}
\includegraphics{graphic.pdf}
\end{rotate}

\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: I can use rotating for certain objects. But how would I do to rotate an entire page? Simply putting all the code between \begin{rotate}{180} and \end{rotate} gives me "Not in outer par mode" errors.

Comment: Can you provide a simplified version of the source which causes this?

Comment: Very simplified:

\begin{turn}{180}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{turn}

Comment: I cannot test this at the moment, but try removing the figure environment:

\begin{turn}{180} \includegraphics{fig}  \end{turn} 

Or if you want to have it for the options at least move the begin/end of figure outside the turn environment:

\begin{figure} \begin{turn}{180} \includegraphics{fig}  \end{turn} \end{figure}

Comment: Another problem example: \begin{rotate}{180}
\begin{center}
hello
\end{center}
\end{rotate}
gives:
"Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item."

Comment: Again, move the center out of the rotate environment: 

"\begin{center} \begin{rotate}{180} hello \end{rotate} \end{center}"

The center environment internally uses trivlist, that's where the error comes from. I tested the graphic example now and it works OK.

Comment: OK, but how would I do if I want to rotate an entire page? I don't want to rotate all objects individually. I hope you agree it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the task, but `\rotatebox{180}` together with `\minipage` can do the job:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]

\newpage

\noindent\rotatebox{180}{\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}\includegraphics{image01.jpg}\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}}

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```